Why "got" not "get" in "we won’t go until we got some"?
sourse: "We Wish You a Merry Christmas"
https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bingcrosby/iwishyouamerrychristmas.html
https://www.lyricsforchristmas.com/christmas-carols/we-wish-you-a-merry-christmas/

And we won’t go until we got some,
and we won’t go until we got some,
and we won’t go until we got some, so bring some out here!
Good tidings we bring to you and your kin.
We wish you a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year.

According to the grammar I've learned, we should say "we won't go until we get some". What's the grammar of the "got" here?

You're citing an invalid rendition. It's we won’t go until we've got some. Or ...until we get some - both versions exist.

I’m voting to close this question because it's citing obviously ungrammatical text

...but this chart shows that the ...until we got some version is definitely gaining traction. Down to lower standards of education, and a higher proportion of non-native Anglophone sources, I suppose.

@FumbleFingers I added two links, and I hope the two transcripts are both wrong.

@Zhang - you have to be careful with lyrics and poetry. You can mess around with English in these forms in a away that you can't with many other languages. In this case "we have got" is grammatically correct but the transcriber has decided it scans better without "have". This explains the more common use of "we get" in this song (and certainly in the version I was familair with). Also, it is important to note that there are no definitive versions of traditional songs like this. There is no original written source.

@FumbleFingers - in your ngrams link you've omitted "some" from the end of the three alternatives. If you add that back in you get very different results ... or am I missing something about how to use ngrams? my version

@timchessish: I don't remember, but one or more of my original search strings may have already had the maximum 5 words. I certainly recall checking that the vast majority of matches were for the figgy pudding song, even though my search strings could have occurred in other contexts. Whatever - so far as I can see, appending some just narrows it down a bit more so only the "idiomatically / syntactically "most natural" version (...won't go until we get some) shows on the chart at all. The Present Perfect version ...until we've got some is "valid" - just not so common.

careful, got some is very slangy/sub-standard. Did you know that? Song lyrics are notorious for that. What you learned is accurate but not how popular culture works in the West.

@FumbleFingers As this answer states, "in very informal American speech" -'ve is often dropped before got, so "we got" = "we've got." But I think the examples in the OP are likely just typos.

@timchessish: I don't buy your the transcriber has decided it scans better without "have". The people who write it liker that are just ignorant (possibly not even native Anglophones). The only reason for dropping have would be for scansion (i.e. - changing the number of syllables). But if present at all here, the word have is always contracted to 've anyway, so it's not a syllable in the first place.

I have a gut feeling that these online sources are made by AI.

It's slang.
The correct use is until we get some.
